# How to develop an app without copying DLLs

Tags: windows, cmake, environment-variables, development-environment

I am using QtCreator to run my application and have a CMake target that copies the DLLs next to my executable every time I press run.

This worked fine, but now I am writing unit tests and for each module, I have a separate executable.

So, the question is how can I avoid copying the DLLs to every single unit test folder, is there anything similar to Linux's `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` on Windows?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, you can just add the build folder to your PATH and it will find the DLLs.